# jQuery form plugin doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm using jQuery form plugin to upload files via ajax. I've tested the scripts and it works in all browsers except IE.It seems that in IE nothing happens(events & ...). I'm working for hours, still no luck.

**PHP:**

```
echo $this->input->post('name');//this is a debuging statement which shows the data sent by client
```

**JS:**

```
$("input[type=file]").on('change',function(){
    $(this).parents('.fileinput-wrapper').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background','url(http://localhost/project/assets/images/ajax-loader.GIF) no-repeat center center');
    var selectedElement = this;
    var name = $(this).attr('name').toString();
    $('#upload').ajaxSubmit({
        //dataType:'json',
        data: {name:name},
        success: function(data) {
            $(selectedElement).parents('.fileinput-wrapper').find('.fileinput-preview').css('background',"url('http://localhost/project/assets/images/loading.png') no-repeat center center");
            return false;
        },
        error : function(xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

What should I do?
(Thanks for help.)

Comment: what a question...DOnt mind my words...I am commenting about IE :(,

Comment: any errors in console? All versions of IE?

Comment: @charlietfl, no I think it doesn't send data to the server, because my log files doesn't show any activity when working with IE

Comment: Do you use js to show the file picker?

Comment: @Musa, what do you mean?

Comment: need more feedback from console..look if request is being made in newtork tab. Is error callback firing? Not giving us much detail. And confirm if errors are thrown in console or not

Comment: Something like `$("input[type=file]").click()`

Comment: I found the bug. I use fileinput plugin which replaces the default file input with a styled element. maybe it doesn't work in IE 9. cause when I disabled it it worked.Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 9 and below doesn't support the XMLHttpRequest Level 2 protocol.  This is required by jQuery to upload files asynchronously.  You'll have to use an iFrame or disable the upload functionality for users with legacy IE browsers.

You can use conditional comments to test for older versions of IE.  Add the following to your JavaScript:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<!--[if lte IE 9]><i></i><![endif]-->";
```

If the variable "div" is set with the `<i></i>` value then you're dealing with an old version of IE